# Sorting DataGridView by Column.DisplayMember

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with a few `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`'s where the actual value is tied to an ID but the `DisplayMember` is the string counterpart in a lookup table. I'm trying to make it so when I sort by that column then the sort is done based on the `DisplayMember`, not the `ValueMember`. I know this was addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2895849/371184) but the answer was less than in depth nor did I understand it.

What I've tried thus far

- Binding to the `SortCompare` event but discovered it isn't fired on a databound column.
- Manually sorting on the `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` event but rows in a `DataGridViewRowCollection` are read-only and I can't programatically insert rows (while swapping) on a databound collection.
- Creating a hidden `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` where the cells are automatically set to the `DisplayMember` of the original column then attempting to sort that column instead. However, a databound collection cannot be sorted based on an unbounded column.

**Edit:** To further clarify: I'm attempting to sort the entire `DataGridView` based on the `DisplayMember` of the comboboxes, not sort the comboboxes themselves.

How can I sort a `DataGridView` based on the `DisplayMember` of a databound `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`?

Comment: can you sort it when querying the table itself? Like ask sql to do ur job?

Comment: Maybe? I know the SQL statement I'd have to use but I'm not sure how to invoke SQL directly on the DataGridView.

Comment: are you not binding your dgv with a datatable or so? In that case how are you populating datatable? I guess you are getting the values from underlying db, aint so?

Comment: I'm sorry if I made that unclear. Yes, the DataGridView is bound to a datatable and then the comboboxes are binding to lookup tables using IDs from the first. But I have that automatically set, I'm not programmatically binding them.

Comment: Oh I missed the point that you are looking for combobox sorting and not the rows of gdv. In that case, how are you getting the lookup table? Is it not possible to sort the lookup table?

Comment: See my edit for clarification on that. Thanks for your help/interest so far :)

Comment: I got it now, but I got to ask you, why not populate the datasource itself based on the display member of lookup table before binding?

Comment: Does this answer you question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943364/1243316

Comment: Dang, that does seem to answer it. I guess I missed that question during my hunt for answers which also means I inadvertently created a duplicate :/ Thanks for the help Brad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third attempt is almost right: What you need to do is create an extra column in your DataSet to store the value of the DisplayMember. Then, you create an invisible bound DataGridViewColumn, and bind it to this extra DataSet column. Then it's a bound column, and you *can* programmatically sort on it.

The question you've linked to is doing the same, only that solution is generating the display member text in SQL, before it's returned to the application.

You'd think this'd be simple, wouldn't you? :)